# drop duplicates on some columns and keep other columns values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table with Postgres:

```
Id   Col1   Col2   Col3
1    A      1      x
2    A      0      y
3    A      0      z
4    B      0      x
5    B      1      y
6    C      0      z
```

As part of a select query, I want to be able to drop duplicates in Col1, based on the highest Col2 values (where will never be multiple highest values per Col1 value), and keep the corresponding Col2, Col3 values.

Desired output:

```
Id   Col1   Col2   Col3
1    A      1      x
5    B      1      y
6    C      0      z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (col1) t.*
from t
order by col1, col2 desc;
```